# Selecting data within a recorded macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to record a macro to automate formatting usage reports. The reports don't all have the same number of rows or columns.

What I want to do is select all columns and rows with data. When recording if I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> it will select the data on that report. However, if I run it on a set of data with more rows or columns it won't include it in the selection.

Is there a way to select from a starting cell to the end of the rows or columns of available data?

Comment: Record your Ctl + Shift + Down + Right using **Use Relative References**. Also Ctrl+A will give you the active cell's CurrentRegion.

Answer (score 0):

Using relative reference will definitely get you the correct coding.  Or you can just put this code `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select` into the appropriate place in the macro (where you put the top leftmost cell in the place of the "A1").

If you want to do more advanced work you can save the current region as a variable and use different properties on it to do things other than simply select the area.

For example:

```
sub test()
dim rng as range
dim rw as integer
dim col as integer

set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'choose the top leftmost cell in the range
rw = rng.rows.count 'counts the number of rows in the selection
col = rng.columns.count 'counts the number of columns
rng.select 'selects the range in an efficient manner
rng.columns(2).select 'selects the second column in the range
rng.rows(2).select 'selects the second row in the range
rng.cells(1,2).select 'selects the cell on the first row and second column in the range

end sub
```

Hopefully this is helpful.  I just wanted to expand on some more things you could do to work with the ranges you have.